# Retrieving data from anonymous class

Tags: java, swing, class

I was wondering how to retrieve the string textOperandValue,from this code :

```
final JTextField textOperand = new JTextField();
textOperand.setBounds(200,100,75,25);

//textOperand action Listener
textOperand.addActionListener( new ActionListener () {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String textOperandValue = textOperand.getText();    
  }
});
```

So I can take it, and then parse it into a double to be used later in the program. I tried setting it equal to a another string 
    `String Input = " ";`  but it said I had to initialize the string to a  `final String Input = " ";`  which I learned is something like a constant in C++.

Comment: I'm wondering how to take the string from the ActionListner and use it in the other part of my code (not included in my question)

Comment: Have you done what the compiler asks and used a final variable? This is indeed the answer...

Comment: @Byron Yeah, I've tried that and its giving me an error saying "Multiple markers at this line
 - The value of the local variable textOperandValue is not used
 - The final local variable textOperandValue cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an 
  enclosing type"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access the members of anonymous classes. In this case it's even a local variable in a method, those are never accessible.

Either, you'll have to set the value of a member of the outer class, but beware of synchronization trouble.

```
class MyClass {
  final JTextField textOperand = new JTextField();
  public String textOperandValue;

  public MyClass() {
    textOperand.setBounds(200,100,75,25);

    //textOperand action Listener
    textOperand.addActionListener( new ActionListener () {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        textOperandValue = textOperand.getText();   
      }
    });
  }

  public someOtherMethod() {
    // textOperandValue available here
    if (textOperandValue != null) 
      //is set
  }
}
```

Or, you'll have to call a method somewhere else that can store the value.

```
class MyClass {
  final JTextField textOperand = new JTextField();

  public MyClass() {
    textOperand.setBounds(200,100,75,25);

    //textOperand action Listener
    textOperand.addActionListener( new ActionListener () {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        someOtherMethod(textOperand.getText()); 
      }
    });
  }

  public someOtherMethod(String value) {
    System.out.println(value);
  }
}
```

Or, you create a (named) class that is an ActionListener and that can store the value in a retrievable form.

```
class MyClass {
  final JTextField textOperand = new JTextField();
  public String textOperandValue;

  private class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {
    String value;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      value =textOperand.getText(); 
    }
  }

  MyActionListener l = new MyActionListener();

  public MyClass() {
    textOperand.setBounds(200,100,75,25);

    //textOperand action Listener
    textOperand.addActionListener(l);
  }

  public someOtherMethod() {
    if (l.value != null) 
      //is set
  }
}
```

Or, you just do what you need to do in the action method:

```
class MyClass {
  final JTextField textOperand = new JTextField();

  public MyClass() {
    textOperand.setBounds(200,100,75,25);

    //textOperand action Listener
    textOperand.addActionListener( new ActionListener () {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(textOperand.getText());
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Any variables you declare within an ActionListener won't be visible to the rest of your code. Either you need to set a variable (from within the listener) that has wider scope:

```
public class Listen
{
    String usefulResult = null;

    public Listen()
    {
        final JTextField textOperand = new JTextField();
        textOperand.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                Listen.this.usefulResult = textOperand.getText();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here we use the "OuterClass.this" trick to access the surrounding scope without needing a final variable.

or you need to perform all the necessary work from within the listener itself (i.e. you don't "retrieve" the value, you just use the value):

```
    public void doSomethingUseful(String usefulValue) { /* add code here */ }

    textOperand.addActionListener( new ActionListener ()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            doSomethingUseful(textOperand.getText());    
        }
    });
```

Or you could use this second technique to call a setter method that changes the value of a variable, avoiding the problems of accessing final variables within event listeners:

```
public class Listen
{
    String usefulResult = null;

    public void setUseful(String usefulValue){
        usefulResult = usefulValue;
    }

    public Listen()
    {
        final JTextField textOperand = new JTextField();
        textOperand.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                setUseful(textOperand.getText());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It depends what you want to do with the value from the TextField.

Comment: Oh, yes - hopefully now fixed.

Comment: @DNA In the first block of code you provided, what does the "Listen.this.(textOperand.getText());" mean? I know that its using the string / line of text type, but I dont know what the Listen.this means

Comment: Also I want to take the value from the JTextField and use it in a formula to calculate the answer of an equation and display it in either a JLabel or a JTextField if possible. @DNA

Comment: `Listen.this` is a way of referring to the instance of the parent class (Listen). We can't use plain `this` because that refers to the inner `EventListener` instance.

Comment: There's lots of detail on using JLabels and JTextfields in the Swing Tutorials: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html

Answer (score 0):

it can work if textOperandValue is global(if it defined in class globally) variable.
not inside ActionListener, not inside method where you wrote this code.